# yii,migrate project to another server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, yii, migrate

I get a project from some provider and I try to migrate the site to another server and all lock fine only I can't make the connection to db.

The original code is this:

```
    <?php
     return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=******',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '********',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
     ];
```

and the code then I modify is this

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=*******',
    'username' => 'evoprom_user',
    'password' => '********',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Do you have some idea?

Comment: what does "can't make the connection to db" mean ??

Comment: Please post specific errors you are receiving.

Comment: Can you please post some error messages?